# Javascript onclick not firing

Tags: javascript

I have a really simple javascript function to return the index of a selected  field, it looks like this:

```
function validateForm() { 
    alert(document.getElementByID('textfieldAmount').selectedIndex);
    return false;
}
```

This is called from an input button onClick like this:

```
onclick="return validateForm();"
```

but the Javascript is never called and the page is submitted anyway.

If i change the alert to alert("wibble"); the alert works fine and the page is not submitted.

The element i am querying looks like this:

```
<select name="textfieldAmount" id="textfieldAmount" class="form">
```

Any ideas why its not working before i kill myself?

Answer (score 5):

javascript is case-sensitive:

```
alert(document.getElementById('textfieldAmount').selectedIndex);
```

Comment: specifically: `ID` should be `Id'